# Ghostscript + DOMPDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript, dompdf

I'm generating PDF files using **DOMPDF** and it generates files with version 1.3 which causes issues in printer. So I tried to use **Ghostscript** through **PHP** `exec()` which works fine but my main PDF parameters like **Author**, **Optimized** etc are reset. So how do we set these info through Ghostscript?

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript doesn't 'reset' the contents of the Info dictionary, these are normally preserved (assuming you are using a reasonably recent version of Ghostscript, you don't actually say which version you are using, nor on which operating system.

If for some reason they are being overwritten, then you can use pdfmark operations to set these contents of the Info dictionary.

I don't know what you mean by 'Optimized'. If you mean 'Linearized' which Distiller often refers to as 'optimized for web viewing' then don't worry about it, its essentially pointless. Effectively this just makes the file bigger.

If you are convinced that you can genuinely use it then you can have Ghostscript produce linearized files too, see Section [6.4](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/VectorDevices.htm#PDFWRITE)